# TFS 2008 Multiple Build Agents Issue

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

We currently use TFS 2008 and have build agents on multiple build servers. I came across this article [Configuring Multiple TFS Build Services on one Machine](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jpricket/archive/2007/08/03/tfs-2008-running-two-build-agents-on-the-same-machine.aspx) which details how to set up multiple agents on one machine and this is a route we'd like to take.

I've set up a new server with 3 agents on it based on the details in the link and each agent has it's own drive on the server to build to.

If I build a project using any one of the agents by itself then it works fine however if I build the same project on each agent at the same time then a very odd thing happens.

Basically two out of the three builds will fail. What I can see in the build output log file is that although the build starts out on the correct drive, at some point during the build it then swaps to the output drive the second agent is using. The build on the second agent will then change to the drive of the 3rd agent and ultimately the 3rd build succeeds.

Each of the build agent services have their own .config file, they all have different port numbers and the properties of the agents are all building to different drives.

Has anyone experienced anything like this before?

Many thanks

Comment: Why do you have more than one TFS server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do something that is not supported by default and I am not surprised that it does not work. You should upgrade to TFS 2013 and move to the Controller/agent model. In TFS 2010+ you can run multiple agents on one box by design.